# How to determine which specific file is rendering a page

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, page-load-time

I am trying to edit the FitPro theme developed by Livemesh for a client. The website has a bad page load speed and I am trying to find where all the CSS and Javascript are called so I can optimize the above the-fold-content.

When using chrome tools, I see where this is happening in the sources tab, it references "(index)" which I am lead to believe is just a name chrome is giving the file that has rendered the content?

How do I figure out specifically what file it is? Because I can't find it. The header, index, front page...they all just reference functions that I can't find without doing a mass search (downloading content now so that I can do this), but this seems like a real pain in the behind.

Is there a better way to know what file to look for?

Answer (score 0):

`(index)` is what Chrome uses for the file name when you access an application without specifying the index in the URL, e.g. if you run `http://localhost/myapp` instead of `http://localhost/myapp/index.html`

You need to find the real index, it may be static or a server script, which renders the content on the server and outputs it to the page.

Comment: To complement: ... wich should be shown in the apache/nginx log in the request on the server, not on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`(index)` means we don't know where the command originated from in the console. This could be due to using things like `eval` which creates a new thread context independent from the page itself.

This means, you're going to need to do some real sleuthing to figure out where things are coming from since what you're looking for is entirely dependent upon what is going on. So within your code set `debugger` statements where you think problems are coming from and walk through what the code is doing.

For CSS, this can mean that the style is originating from a `<style>` element in the HTML in which case it is from the "Index file" of the page. That would be whatever the HTML file is for a given resource.